# Typescript/Prisma: Can't Generate CRUD Operations with Custom Resolvers

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

### Problem

I'm new to [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/setup/generating-the-client-rsc1/), and I just followed a few tutorials to get my database hosted locally via Docker. (I'm using Typescript as my language).

I've written a few custom resolvers for user creation in separate files (my file structure is as follows), and I am trying to access these resolvers on my server endpoint after I deploy my server using `prisma deploy`.

```
File Structure:
---
- graphql-schema
  - prisma.graphql  <-- where my schema is defined
- prisma
  - ...
- prisma-client-js
  - ...
- prisma-client-ts
  - ...
- src
  - generated
  - resolvers       <-- where my custom resolvers
- datamodel.prisma  <-- where my data models are defined
- package.json
- prisma.yml
- tsconfig.json
- yarn.lock
```

After deployment onto `localhost`, all of the `createModel`, `updateModel`, etc. operations are generated for each of my datamodels, but my `signUp` and `logIn` functions aren't.

### Question

Is it possible to deploy my GraphQL server with both CRUD operations and custom resolvers? If so, how? I'm using Prisma 1.26.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can expose with of these operations. Just import the prisma ones from the prisma.graphql file using graphql-import and define them in the resolvers. https://github.com/prisma/graphql-import

Here is an example project using this approach: https://github.com/javascript-af/javascript-af/blob/master/packages/backend/src/schema.graphql

There is also new project which simplifies this process quite a lot: https://github.com/prisma/nexus-prisma